# How to use Yesod.Auth.Email without email confirmation?

Tags: authentication, haskell, yesod

All I need is the following:

1. Register new user with email and password without sending any emails. Just enter email and two fields for password (second for checking typo in password) and new user will created in the database with salted password.
2. Login with just form with email and password. UserId saved in session.
3. Form with changing password for user. (two fields for new password and third for old password).
4. Logout button. UserId removed from the session.

Can it be reached with `Yesod.Auth.Email` or, if not, how to do that in Yesod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [HashDB article on cookbook](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Using-HashDB-In-a-Scaffolded-Site).

3 is just a page where these fields can be changed from the db.

4 is a link to AuthR LogoutR